# Combined react router prefix with rails route-- causing routing error?

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm sort of new to ruby on rails and react. I'm having an issue making a patch request from my react.js frontend to my ruby on rails backend. The path from my route is somehow prepended to my rails route, thus causing a routing error like so:

```
Started PATCH "/edit/api/organizations/1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2022-06-06 21:06:34 -0500
  
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [PATCH] "/edit/api/organizations/1"):
```

My route is supposed to be `api/organizations/1` ,
without `edit` in front of it.
It seems related to my router, since I've created this route:

```
 <Route exact path='/edit/:id' element={<EditOrganization  selectedOrg={selectedOrg}selectOrg={selectOrg} user={user} />}></Route>
```

My fetch request in React:

```
fetch(`api/organizations/${selectedOrg.id}`, {
    method: "PATCH",
    headers: {
        "Content-Type" : "application/json"
    }, 
    body: JSON.stringify({name, hourly_rate: hourlyRate})
})...
```

I've also created a fallback controller, I thought this would resolve some conflicts between router and rails routes, perhaps I didn't do it correctly.
In my `routes.rb` file, I've added this as the last route.

```
  get "*path", to: "fallback#index", constraints: ->(req) { !req.xhr? && req.format.html? }
```

`app/controllers/fallback_controller.rb`

```
class FallbackController < ActionController::Base
    def index
      render file: 'public/index.html'
    end
  end
```

Maybe I'm way off base and my question is probably a bit confusing. But I thought I'd give it a shot. Any help would be very appreciated :)

Comment: Wow. well I feel really silly! All I had to do was prepend a ```/``` to my fetch request so it would be recognized locally. I can't believe I spent so much time trying to figure that out! The solution was so simple... probably a good indicator I need to take more breaks!

Comment: If it was related to the route then I'd suspect the PATCH request url would look something more like `"/edit/someId/api/organizations/someOtherId"`. Can you edit your question to include all the frontend routing and component code making the request? I suspect you might just need to prefix the PATCH request with a `"/"` character so it's an absolute path.

Comment: Ah, nevermind, looks like you figured it out the same way I was suggesting at the same time.

Comment: Instead of editing the title to mark your question "resolved", it would be better to supply an answer, and accept it since you were able to resolve it yourself.

Comment: Thanks so much for taking the time to look over my question and offer up a solution, Drew. Also was wondering how I should handle resolving it myself on here.  I'll go ahead and add an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I was missing the `/` before my PATCH request. It needed the `/` to be recognized as a relative path.

```
fetch(`/api/organizations/${selectedOrg.id}`, {
    method: "PATCH",
    headers: {
        "Content-Type" : "application/json"
    }, 
    body: JSON.stringify({name, hourly_rate: hourlyRate})
})...
```